# count Errors messages in a log file

Tags: text-processing, logs

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'current_state' at r:1
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'current_state' at r:2
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'current_state' at r:5
java.lang.NullPointerException:12
java.lang.NullPointerException:7
java.lang.NullPointerException:18
java.lang.NullPointerException:2
```

As you can see I have 3 duplicated mysql error and they have their frequency appears at the end. On the first error it appears 1, on the secand error it appears 2 and on the third time it appears 5.
I want script to remain one duplicated line with sum. Doing the same for the java errors.

Expected output:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'current_state' at r:8
java.lang.NullPointerException:39
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS=":" }
   { freq=$NF; sub(/:[^:]*$/, ""); seen[$0]+=freq }
END{ for (x in seen) print x, seen[x] }' infile
```

FS is the input field separator and OFS is the output field separator; both we set to a colon; then we grab the last field `$NF` into a temporary variable `freq` and then remove the last field from the current input record `$0` using sub() functoin.

by doing `seen[$0]+=freq` we are summing-up the same log lines (last field is already excluded) on the last field's value as their frequency we hold in the `freq` variable previously.

then at the END we loop over the array and print the lines followed by their total frequency.